# Dynamically changing text color of text field

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Team,

I am facing one issue where I am not able to change text color of xtype:textfield. I am using EXTJS 3.4

Requirement is to show default text like "Fill your details here" in gray color initially.

But when user focuses on that field I am removing the default text so that user can enter appropriate value.

I want to change the color of text to black from grey when user enters some value. Is there any way we can do this with ExtJS 3.4

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the emptyText config.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-cfg-emptyText.  It shows gray initially and when the user enters a value it clears and the entered text is black.

```
new Ext.form.TextField({renderTo: Ext.getBody(), emptyText: 'Fill Details Here'})
```

Comment: I do believe that emptyText shows gray by default. Just one caution: the value of emptyText will be submitted with the form if the field has a name.

Comment: @Derek yeah that is what it says in the docs in the link.  In 4 it looks like this can be handled with the submitEmptyText config on form basic.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use

```
new Ext.form.TextField({renderTo: Ext.getBody(), id:'textId', emptyText: 'Fill Details Here'})
```

and on submit check for emptyness and empty both and put a validation.

```
Ext.Button({
text:'title',
handler:function(btn,optn){
var value = Ext.getCmp('textId').getValue();
```

// here .getValue() removes undefined and empty text and gives as ''

```
if(value === ''){
   Ext.msg.alert('Validation', 'Please fill all the mandatory fields');
}
}
```

});